# Cloudflare configuration for AWS Amplify

Tags: dns, aws-amplify, cloudflare

Followed the instructions from here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html)

[image]

For this required configuration, I have added 2 CNAME records in the Cloudflare account. But still my domain is not active.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the 1st image in the question, You should enter the value which starts with `_41ae3b45....` as `name` in the cloudflare dns CNAME record.

Refer the edited image and this worked for me

[image]